# contracts.ContractReverted: The contract ran to completion but decided to revert its storage changes. Ink nft smart contract

Tags: polkadot, ink, smart-contract, nft

I am trying to call the `set_base_uri` function and the `mint_next` function of the ink! NFT smart contract. When calling from `polkadot-ui` it is working correctly but when I call it using `nextjs` it gives a dispatch error

I am calling it with:

```js
      const handleMint = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
    
            const getGasMaxLimit = () => {
                return api.registry.createType(
                    "WeightV2",
                    api.consts.system.blockWeights["maxBlock"]
                );
            };
    
            console.log("gas limit max", getGasMaxLimit().toHuman());
    
            try {
                const res = await contract.query["payableMint::mintNext"](
                    state.data.defaultAccount.address,
                    {
                        storageDepositLimit: null,
                        gasLimit: getGasMaxLimit(),
                    }
                );
    
                const { output, result, gasRequired, storageDeposit } = res;
                console.log("mintNext query result", result.toString());
                console.log("mint gasRequired", gasRequired.toString());
                console.log("storageDeposit", storageDeposit.toString());
    
        
                const mintResult = await contract.tx["payableMint::mintNext"]({
                    storageDepositLimit: null,
                    gasLimit: api.registry.createType("WeightV2", gasRequired),
                }).signAndSend(
                    state.data.defaultAccount.address,
                    { signer: injector.signer },
                    (result) => {
                        if (result.dispatchError) {
                            let dispatchError = result.dispatchError;
                            if (dispatchError.isModule) {
                                // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
                                const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(
                                    dispatchError.asModule
                                );
                                const { docs, name, section } = decoded;
                                console.log(
                                    `Transaction Failed\n  ${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(
                                        " "
                                    )}`
                                );
                            } else {
                                console
                                    .log(
                                        `Transaction Failed\n  ${dispatchError.toString()}`
                                    )
                                    .then(() => {
                                        window.location.reload();
                                    });
                            }
                        } else if (result.isInBlock) {
                            console.log("Transaction successful");
                        }
                    }
                );
    
                setIsMinted(true);
                dispatch(setMinted(true));
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        };
```

The error is:

```
> Transaction Failed   contracts.ContractReverted: The contract ran to
> completion but decided to revert its storage changes. Please note that
> this error is only returned from extrinsics. When called directly or
> via RPC an `Ok` will be returned. In this case the caller needs to
> inspect the flags to determine whether a reversion has taken place.
```